# Wifi pcmcia cards not working anymore on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, pcmcia

I used to be able to access the net, via wifi, on my ubuntu laptop.

But now, the system doesn't see any wifi networks, and *dmesg* shows me weird messages.

I have two different cards, and none of them seem to work, even though the second one looks promising.

**Netgear 108Mbps Wireless PC Card WG511T :**

here's what I get when I remove and re-insert the card

```
#demsg
[   27.815902] eth0: link down
[   27.816161] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  116.912042] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: pccard: CardBus card inserted into slot 0
[  116.912072] pci 0000:03:00.0: unknown header type 03, ignoring device
```

Any ideas on that problem ? Is my wifi card dead ?

**Linksys Wireless-G Notebook Adapter
Model No WPC54G v. 1.2**

```
[  615.592031] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: pccard: CardBus card inserted into slot 0
[  615.592095] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 10 32bit mmio: [0x000000-0x001fff]
[  615.592163] pci 0000:03:00.0: supports D1 D2
[  615.592168] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[  615.592176] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# disabled
[  616.213753] b43-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  616.213779] b43-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[  616.213807] b43-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  616.219864] ssb: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:03:00.0
[  616.760573] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  617.235690] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  617.235700]  (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  617.235705]  (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  617.235710]  (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  617.235715]  (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  617.235720]  (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  617.235725]  (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  617.399606] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4306 WLAN found
[  617.446405] phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'pid'
[  617.694275] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PLR, Firmware-ID: FW13 ]
[  617.708155] udev: renamed network interface wlan0 to wlan1
```

(note : I have used the "system test" tool to generate a detailed report of my ubuntu install. It is too big to copy here, but ask if you think a pertinent piece of info could be in it, I'll look).

Comment: I found that guy who has the same problem (but there's no answer)
http://osdir.com/ml/drivers.madwifi.devel/2005-01/msg00050.html

Comment: May not be relevant but I have had problems occasionally when installing proposed updates has stopped wifi working. Installing fully tested updates is more reliable. If you can, try going back to the kernel and modules that worked, see if it still works and move forward from there.

Comment: I played around with some settings in iwconfig (on a livecd) Could that cause this problem ?

Comment: does it recognize the card on the liveCD?

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Nope, I've got the same messages using the Ubuntu Live CD, and using Backtrack 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pcmcia slot may be dead, it's an old pc. I now have internet access, with an usb wifi and ndiswraper.

Too bad nobody could answer me on WTF "*unknown header type 03*" is.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to lean this way a little too much, but it has solved my wireless problems many times...

try installing the linux backports modules for your version of ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-jaunty
```

replace jaunty with your version.

Comment: What exactly does this command do ?

Comment: Can I donwload a .deb package ? I have no internet access on the linux box.

Comment: I believe you can get the .deb from packages.ubuntu.com, just find the module for your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: much easier than trying to get the right kernel module on one's own.